# How to put the numerical range to the definite integral function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am new to *Mathematica* so I couldn't put the values of `T = 90`, `p = 2.510924` and `k = 42.629044` in the integral. Can you please tell me how to put the values?

```
Integrate[y^(p-3) Log(y) E^-y^p, {y, 0, T/k}]
```

Comment: `T = 90; p = 2.510924 ; k = 42.629044;
NIntegrate[y^(p - 3) Log[y] E^-y^p, {y, 0, T/k}]` gives `-3.7174`.

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error, you are suppose to use `Log[]`not `Log()`.

**Method I**

Follow @corey979 comment.

**Method II**

```
With[{T = 90, p = 2.510924, k = 42.629044}, 
        NIntegrate[y^(p - 3) Log[y] E^-y^p, {y, 0, T/k}]]
```

**Method III**

```
NIntegrate[(y^(p - 3) Log[y] E^-y^p) /. {p -> 2.510924}, {y, 0, 
           (T/k) /. {T -> 90, k -> 42.629044}}]
```

Comment: @corey979 thank u so much sir...